# Django OneToOneField Relationship Access

Tags: django, one-to-one

Hey I'm kinda disoriented right now. I have a simple question.

Well I got this model.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model)

   user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
   bool = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and then I want to access this "bool" field from my admin.py and at one point I would like to test if the bool is True or False.

```
def some_method(request)
```

if its some bool in the standard user-model I would test like

```
if request.user.standard_bool:
```

but how do I do this in order to access my bool defined in the models.py?
I thought that would be

```
if request.user.profile.bool:
```

but it gives me "User has no profile."

P.S.
I ended up finding out that this was not the root of my problem.
After I tried the suggested solutions it still didnt work.. until I 
changed the save and create_user_profile of my UserProfile class to save the profile right. Nevertheless I will mark this as solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`request.user` is associated with `django-auth User Model`

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=request.user.username)
if user.profile.bool:
```

remember `profile` in `user.profile.bool` is from `related_name='profile'` under your UserProfile Model

Comment: Since, as you say, `request.user` is an instance of User, why would you query it again from the username? Just do `request.user.profile.bool`.

Comment: request.user is not instance of User, user is instance of user

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear.  You don't have a `UserProfile` instance for the logged user.

You can workaround such situation with the following code:

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
if profile and profile.bool:
    ...
```